# How to view two tables in one gridview?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench

I have two tables with same columns. What I want to know is How can I view the two tables from database into One datagridview?

here is my code

```
con = New MySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = cons
ds = New Dataset
tables = ds.Tables

da = New MysqlDataAdapter("Select * from haspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "'",con)
d1 = New MysqlDataAdapter("Select * from laspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "'",con)
da.Fill(ds, "hapostingusername")
da1.Fill(ds, "lapostingusername")
Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
DgvReport.DataSource = view
```

help me please. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a union and returning the results in one go.
So instead of

```
da = New MysqlDataAdapter("Select * from haspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "'",con)
d1 = New MysqlDataAdapter("Select * from laspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "'",con)
```

you could try

```
foobar = New MysqlDataAdapter("Select * from haspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & " UNION Select * from laspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "'",con)
```

Additionally, if the `txtUser` is input from the user you should wrap it in a prepared statement to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: How to Union? I dont know haha

Comment: Its okay now. thank you very much! :) is my code: 

da = New MysqlDataAdapter("Select * from haspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "' UNION ALL Select * from laspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "'",con)

Comment: Check the second code example I provided. Assuming I didn't typo it should be usable as such. In other words, I took your two separate SELECT clauses and joined them with UNION into a single SQL query. This will work as long as the columns are the same and in some cases you can even add dummy columns to a SELECT to make them match, but in your case that's not necessary.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @ronnie-jimenez did you unaccept the answer by accident or did something in your setup change and the union stopped working?

Comment: @JussiV ohh sorry. It was by accident. Sorry friend.

Comment: No worries, just saw your response changed and wondered if something in your setup changed that broke the union and already wondered if adding dummy columns would resolve it, but all is still good :)

Answer (score 0):

Its okay now. thank you very much! :) is my code:

```
da = New MysqlDataAdapter("Select * from haspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "' UNION ALL Select * from laspostingusername where User ='" & txtUser.Text & "'",con)
```